# Thicker line to separate a `LaTeX` code and its output

Tags: tcolorbox

How can I obtain a thicker line dashed line between the `LaTeX` code and its output in the code above?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{doclatex}{listing side text}

\begin{document}

\begin{doclatex}
$just + A = test$
\end{doclatex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to find your way into `segmentation engine` and `segmentation style`.

Comment: Ok. I will play later with this. I have to go to see a movie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{doclatex}{enhanced, listing side text, segmentation style={line width=2pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{doclatex}
$just + A = test$
\end{doclatex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have missed the `most` option... Thanks for the ready-to-use code.